# wagtail django list index out of range

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, wagtail

Can you please help me with this issue. I am trying to add show only tranlated menu title. And adding this code to my tags file:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('home/tags/top_menu.html', takes_context=True)
def top_menu(context, parent, calling_page=None):
    request = context['request']
    language_code = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
    menuitems = parent.get_children().live().in_menu().filter(title = language_code)[0].get_children()
    for menuitem in menuitems:
        menuitem.show_dropdown = has_menu_children(menuitem)
        menuitem.active = (calling_page.path.startswith(menuitem.path)
                           if calling_page else False)
    return {
        'calling_page': calling_page,
        'menuitems': menuitems,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

But I am getting this error on page : 
 list index out of range and highlighted code

> {% top_menu parent=site_root calling_page=self %}

Using Wagtail 1.12 and Python 3.6.2

Answer (score 2):

`parent.get_children().live().in_menu().filter(title = language_code)[0]`

You don't account for the possibility that `.filter(title = language_code)` returns an empty list.

You should either use `try-except` or divide this part of the code to several lines and then check if `.filter` returned an empty list.

For example:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('home/tags/top_menu.html', takes_context=True)
def top_menu(context, parent, calling_page=None):
    request = context['request']
    language_code = request.LANGUAGE_CODE 
    try:
        menuitems = parent.get_children().live().in_menu().filter(title = language_code)[0].get_children()
    except IndexError:
        menuitems = []
    else:  # you don't actually need to have 'else' in this case
        for menuitem in menuitems:
            menuitem.show_dropdown = has_menu_children(menuitem)
            menuitem.active = (calling_page.path.startswith(menuitem.path)
                               if calling_page else False)
    return {
        'calling_page': calling_page,
        'menuitems': menuitems,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```